# generating two files by using workflows in Teamsite

Tags: perlscript

I need your help/suggestion in teamsite(V6.7) coding for generating two files by using workflows means "How to generate  a page at two different locations (in same branch) by using two different tpl files(desktop.tpl and mobile.tpl) but same DCR(abc.xml)"
I  also guessed the idea/scenario that if any Perl script can be added in existing Workflow and while submitting the desktop file by using workflow to desktop location (/servername/default/main/sitefoldername/desktopsite/) then this workflow will also generate the same named file in mobile location(servername/default/main/sitefoldername/mobilesite/mobilepages/)
Please let me know if this kind of script can be developed
 It would be a great help for me if you can provide your best solution into this.

Answer (score 0):

Update the {iw-home}/local/config/templating.cfg to include the multiple presentations, one for each of your tpl file. You can use formAPI to set the location of the generated files.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely generate two pages at a time.
You need to update the "*templating.cfg*" file and add all the different .tpl file names that you want to use but after doing this just try to generate some files using UI to cross check whether you are able to get the options for tpl selections if yes then you can proceed with the coding stuff. Also, you can refer some of these files: *iwgen.ipl, iwpt_compile.ipl, iwtmplconfig.ipl and iwregen.ipl*.

Please mark the solution and vote if it is useful.

**Thanks!**